# Jquery Mobile Nuget package crashing VS 2015 Tools for Cordova projects

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-cordova

I am playing with a couple small Cordova projects in VS 2015 using Tools for Apache Cordova project type. They build and deploy fine. Every time I add JQuery Mobile, the IDE freezes up before completing. I have to use Task Manager to end the process. Afterwards, I run the Nuget package a second time and it completes. 
Any ideas what might be happening here?

Others seeing similar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. I've taken a crash dump and filed a bug for us to investigate.

In the meantime, I recommend either adding jquery mobile by hand (ie not through the NuGet package manager), or trying to add the regular NuGet package - which seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks Michael, that is what I have done. It's easy enough. Was just trying to embrace the Nuget route. Since Nuget installs jQuery in the root of the project, which is not where we need it for a Cordova project, it is probably best to install manually for these projects. Thanks again

Comment: FYI - we have fixed this bug and it will be released in the next update to the Tools for Apache Cordova. Thanks again for reporting it!